# Deriving a formula for the interior product on $1$-covectors

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

> For $1$-covectors $\alpha^1, \dots, \alpha^k$ on a vector space $V$ and $v \in V$, show that $$\iota_v(\alpha^1 \wedge \dots \wedge \alpha^k)= \sum_{i=1}^k(-1)^{i-1}\alpha^i(v)\alpha^1\wedge \dots\wedge \widehat{\alpha^i} \wedge \dots\wedge \alpha^k$$ where the caret means that the $i$'th index is omitted and $\iota$ denotes the interior product.

Starting to compute this I got to the point that $$\begin{align*} \iota_v(\alpha^1 \wedge \dots \wedge \alpha^k)(v_2,\dots,v_k) &=  (\alpha^1 \wedge \dots \wedge \alpha^k)(v,v_2,\dots,v_k) \\ &= \det\begin{bmatrix} 
    \alpha^1(v) & \dots  & \alpha^1(v_k)\\
    \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
    \alpha^k(v) & \dots  & \alpha^k(v_k)
    \end{bmatrix}.\end{align*}$$

What I then considered was the sum formula for the determinant using permutations, but I coulnd't mold it to the form they're looking for. Can this determinant be manipulated using row operations or some other trick which would give something to work with?

Comment: This is just an expansion of the determinant along the first column

Comment: My linear algebra is a bit rusty. Didn't we need some cofactors for that? @Didier

Comment: Yes, but the cofactors are exactly $\alpha^1\wedge \cdots\wedge  \hat{\alpha}^i\wedge \cdots \wedge \alpha^k$. (Didn't you mean $i_v(\alpha^1\wedge \cdots \wedge \alpha^k)$ instead of $i_v(\alpha^1,\ldots,\alpha^k)$, by the way?)

Comment: @Didier I did! Edited the question. The cofactor expansion along the first column gives us that $$\det(A) = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha^i(v_1)C_{i,1} = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha^i(v_1) (-1)^{i+1}\det(A_{i,1})$$ but this isn't quite in the form we're after.

Comment: Yes it is: expand the cofactors (and notice that $(-1)^{i+1} = (-1)^{i-1}$). Recall that $\alpha^{i_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge\alpha^{i_{k-1}}(v_{j_1},\ldots,v_{j_{k-1}})$ is given by some determinant

Comment: $A_{i,1}$ denotes the matrix where we "hide" the $i$'th row and first column. How can we expand this $\det(A_{i,1})$ further? Also for convinience $v_1 := v$ here. @Didier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You arrived at
$$
i_{v_1}(\alpha^1\wedge\cdots\wedge\alpha^k)(v_2,\ldots,v_k) =
\det (\alpha^i(v_j))_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant k}.
$$
On the one hand, expanding along the first column, we get
$$
i_{v_1}(\alpha^1\wedge\cdots\wedge\alpha^k)(v_2,\ldots,v_k) =
\sum_{i=1}^k (-1)^{i-1}\alpha^1(v_i) \det (\alpha^{\tilde{i}}(v_j))_{1\leqslant {\tilde{i}},j\leqslant k\\{\tilde{i}}\neq i, j \neq 1}.
$$
On the other hand, one has
$$
(\alpha^1\wedge\cdots\wedge \hat{\alpha}^i\wedge\cdots\wedge\alpha^k)(v_2,\ldots,v_k) = \det(\alpha^{\tilde{i}}(v_j))_{1\leqslant {\tilde{i}} \leqslant k, {\tilde{i}} \neq i\\ 2 \leqslant j \leqslant k},
$$
which is precisely the cofactor we were looking for.
It follows that
$$
i_{v_1}(\alpha^1\wedge\cdots\wedge\alpha^k)(v_2,\ldots,v_k) =
\sum_{i=1}^k (-1)^{i-1}\alpha^1(v_i)(\alpha^1\wedge\cdots\wedge \hat{\alpha}^i\wedge\cdots\wedge\alpha^k)(v_2,\ldots,v_k).
$$
This being true for all $v_2,\ldots,v_k$, the result follows.